# How to boot encrypted windows partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, encryption

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 on a dedicated partition in my work machine. The Windows partition is encrypted with Symantec full disk encryption, and is not recognized by Ubuntu as Windows (and does not appear on grub).

Below is the output of fdisk -l (windows partition is /dev/sda2):

```
Disk /dev/sda: 256.1 GB, 256060514304 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 31130 cylinders, total 500118192 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x80145d38

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     1023999      510976    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         1024000   382060543   190518272    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       382060544   383059967      499712   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4       383062014   489504767    53221377    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       383062016   422121471    19529728   83  Linux
/dev/sda6       422123520   461182975    19529728   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       461185024   462159871      487424   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       462161920   475832319     6835200   83  Linux
/dev/sda9       475834368   489504767     6835200   83  Linux
```

A link to the boot info script output:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/10775071/

I am looking for some way in which I can boot my Windows again in any possible way (even if it means deleting the Ubuntu OS I've just installed - I don't have anything important on it yet).
Just need some way to access the information on my Windows encrypted partition.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you read http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH149679 ?

Comment: The best thing to do is to to a complete [image restore](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) of your disk before you installed Ubuntu.  If you don't have such a back-up , the best you can do is to contact your Symantec support channels and probably unencrypt the disk completely before continuing...